# StreamingQueryException: batch 0 doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to use spark streaming for file sources. I am trying to apply streaming for json files. I created a folder `input` for the files to which spark will read. I created a folder `output` for the output json files. For this purpose I ran the following script

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from lib.logger import Log4j
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("File Streaming Demo") \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", "true") \
        .getOrCreate()

    logger = Log4j(spark)
    
    raw_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("json") \
        .option("path", "C:/Users/ivan/SparkProjects/Spark-Streaming-In-Python/02-FileStreamDemo/input") \
        .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) \
        .option("cleanSource","delete") \
        .load()

    # raw_df.printSchema()
    
    explode_df = raw_df.selectExpr("InvoiceNumber", "CreatedTime", "StoreID", "PosID",
                                   "CustomerType", "PaymentMethod", "DeliveryType", "DeliveryAddress.City",
                                   "DeliveryAddress.State",
                                   "DeliveryAddress.PinCode", "explode(InvoiceLineItems) as LineItem")
    
    explode_df.printSchema()
    
    
    print(type(explode_df))
    
    
    flattened_df = explode_df \
        .withColumn("ItemCode", expr("LineItem.ItemCode")) \
        .withColumn("ItemDescription", expr("LineItem.ItemDescription")) \
        .withColumn("ItemPrice", expr("LineItem.ItemPrice")) \
        .withColumn("ItemQty", expr("LineItem.ItemQty")) \
        .withColumn("TotalValue", expr("LineItem.TotalValue")) \
        .drop("LineItem")
       
    flattened_df.printSchema() 

    invoiceWriterQuery = flattened_df.writeStream \
        .format("json") \
        .queryName("Flattened Invoice Writer") \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .option("path", "C:/Users/ivan/SparkProjects/Spark-Streaming-In-Python/02-FileStreamDemo/output") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "chk-point-dir") \
        .trigger(processingTime="1 minute") \
        .start()
        
    logger.info("Flattened Invoice Writter started")
    
    invoiceWriterQuery.awaitTermination()
```

but I get the following error

```
22/05/02 14:08:15 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query Flattened Invoice Writer [id = 6bbb72a1-a424-4b7e-8b8b-a608324ec909, runId = ff7bdac4-c42e-41d1-8c4b-9a49b87afa5d] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: batch 0 doesn't exist
```

despite the fact that the printSchema() attribute works

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
root
 |-- InvoiceNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreatedTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StoreID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PosID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomerType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PaymentMethod: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DeliveryType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PinCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LineItem: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ItemCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ItemDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ItemPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ItemQty: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TotalValue: double (nullable = true)

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
root
 |-- InvoiceNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreatedTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StoreID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PosID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CustomerType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PaymentMethod: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DeliveryType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PinCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemQty: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalValue: double (nullable = true)
```

I would really appreaciate any hint to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by checkpointLocation because checkpointLocation stores old or deleted data information. Delete the folder containing checkpointLocation and run again.